# Aidl can not be executed, Buildozer

Tags: kivy, buildozer

I am using an Raspberry pi 4 and when I run

```
buildozer android debug
```

it says aidl cannot be executed

I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this problem

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry pi is not supported, I just used a ubuntu virtual machine